# Why my css changes are not getting reflected?

Tags: css, html, border

My css changes are not getting reflected in `html5` , there's no braces problem I also did   <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>f5</kbd>  and I ran the same code in some other path and also I ran it in some other browser but the problem seem to be there .

Here's my HTMLs code :

```css
.div1 {
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px;
  /*background-color : "red";*/
}
.div2 {
  max-width: 50%;
  /*background-color : "blue";*/
}
.div3 {
  max-width: 50%;
  /*background-color :"green";*/
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">p</div>
<div class="div2">q</div>
<div class="div3">r</div>
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong ? any of CSS change is not reflected I see white document without any div

Comment: What exactly needs to be reflected and it doesn't ?

Comment: @DeneaNovac Edited in the question

Comment: Do you mean the background-color doesn't change or what?

Comment: "White document without any div"? You mean not even the text content inside the divs is showing? That doesn't sound like a CSS issue...

Comment: Is your stylesheet really called "java.css" and is it in the same directory as that HTML file/page?

Comment: @Serlite the texts are coming but none of the cSS properties are reflected

Comment: @Johannes yes they are in the same directory

Comment: are you aware that the background-colors *won't* be displayed with that code since they are commented out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) syntax is wrong, because you are not setting a `border-style`.

the formal syntax is this one:

```
<br-width> || <br-style> || <color>
```

Here are the values:

> `<br-width>`
>
> Default value medium is used if absent. See [border-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width).
>
> `<br-style>`
>
> Default value none is used if absent. See [border-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style).
>
> `<color>`
>
> A [`<color>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) denoting the color of the border. If not set, its default value is the value of the element's color property (the text
>   [color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color), not the background color). See [border-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color).

---

```css
.div1 {
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  /*background-color : "red";*/
}
.div2 {
  max-width: 50%;
  /*background-color : "blue";*/
}
.div3 {
  max-width: 50%;
  /*background-color :"green";*/
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">p</div>
<div class="div2">q</div>
<div class="div3">r</div>
```

Comment: thatks it worked but does that mean border will on ly work if we give style giving only the border width  alone won't work ?

Comment: yup because `border-style` says `Default value none is used if absent`, so if `none`, means no style for `border`

Answer (score 1):

Try use a specific color and type of the border, Eg:

```
border : 1px solid red;
```

Answer (score 0):

give border with color `border:1px solid black`

**or** 
have a background color `background-color :green;` (N.B : No quotation on the color name)